# using Filament Group's customInput plugin inside jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using Filament Group's customInput plugin.

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/accessible_custom_designed_checkbox_radio_button_inputs_styled_css_jquery/

It's always worked fine in the past, but now with the inputs inside a jQuery UI dialog, 
the inputs don't respond to any click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried deep down in the comments of the Filament Group article, 
one commenter notes this same problem, and that he resolved it by 
increasing the z-index of the inputs and labels to a z-index higher 
than that of the jQuery UI dialog. The z-index of the jQuery UI dialog 
appears to start at 1002.

Adjusting the z-index of the inputs and labels did indeed fix the problem for me.